# Build cubic root function in r that returns both negative and positive numbers

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a cubic root function that returns this output:

```
cr(27)
```

output:

```
3
```

```
cr(-27)
```

output:

```
-3
```

I tried the following:

```
cr<- function(x){
  if(x < 0 & x> 0 & x== 0){
    cat("Error, not possible ")
  }
  else{
    cat((x^(1/3)))
    cat(" ")
  } 
}
```

I'm getting error for -27:

```
Nan
```

Comment: your conditional should be fixed: `if(x < 0 & x> 0 & x== 0)` will never be true

Comment: @rawr what do you mean will never be true? I tried Paul's answer and it worked.

Comment: that's a separate question. `x` can never be strictly negative _and_ strictly positive _and_ equal to 0 simultaneously

Comment: @rawr how to fix it?

Comment: @rawr also, can you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191602/remove-kind-of-data-from-a-column-when-plotting-using-barplot-in-r-not-ggplot

Comment: it's not clear what you want. x^1/3 is normally defined for all x >= 0 but you specifically want it defined for all real numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is giving you one of the cube roots. The one it's giving you happens to be complex.

```
x <- -27

as.complex(x)^(1 / 3)
#> [1] 1.5+2.598076i
```

If you want the real root, calculate it like this.

```
sign(x) * abs(x)^(1 / 3)
#> [1] -3
```

Comment: Thank you! @Paul , it worked, I'm new to coding, can you explain the code?

Comment: `abs(x)` gets the absolute value of `x` (27). `abs(x)^(1 / 3)` gives the real root, `3`, but it has the wrong sign.

`sign(x)` is `-1` if `x` is negative and `1` if `x` is positive. So multiplying by `sign(x)` fixes the sign.

Comment: Thanks! @Paul, I already accepted and upvoted your answer, I have another question if you could help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186879/how-to-get-stacked-bar-of-three-variables-in-two-bars-in-r-with-the-use-of-base?noredirect=1#comment113505991_64186879