# Remove kind of data from a column when plotting using barplot in r (not ggplot)

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the boxplot of chess_games$cream_rating~chess_games$victory_status

Data:

```
A data.frame: 6 × 8
    rated   turns   victory_status  winner  increment_code  cream_rating    charcoal_rating   opening_name
    <lgl>   <int>   <fct>          <fct>    <fct>            <int>          <int>              <fct>
1   FALSE   13     outoftime       cream    15+2             1500           1191              Slav Defense: Exchange Variation
2   TRUE    16      resign        charcoal  5+10             1322           1261              Nimzowitsch Defense: Kennedy Variation
3   TRUE    61      mate           cream    5+10             1496           1500              King's Pawn Game: Leonardis Variation
4   TRUE    61      mate           cream    20+0            1439            1454              Queen's Pawn Game: Zukertort Variation
5   TRUE    95      mate           cream    30+3            1523            1469              Philidor Defense
6   FALSE   5       draw            draw    10+0            1250            1002              Sicilian Defense: Mongoose Variation
```

When I try this code:

```
chess_games_rated<-chess_games$cream_rating 
chess_games_victory<-chess_games$victory_status
boxplot(chess_games_rated~chess_games_victory)
```

I get:

[image]

Why I'm getting draws when I suppose not, how to remove draws from the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't filter it out?

```
boxplot(cream_rating ~ victory_status, chess_games[!chess_games$winner %in% "draw", ])
```

[image]

*Data:*

```
chess_games <- structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE
), turns = c(13L, 16L, 61L, 61L, 95L, 5L), victory_status = c("outoftime", 
"resign", "mate", "mate", "mate", "draw"), winner = c("cream", 
"charcoal", "cream", "cream", "cream", "draw"), increment_code = c("15+2", 
"5+10", "5+10", "20+0", "30+3", "10+0"), cream_rating = c(1500L, 
1322L, 1496L, 1439L, 1523L, 1250L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 
1261L, 1500L, 1454L, 1469L, 1002L), opening_name = c("Slav", 
"Nimzowitsch", "King", "Queen", "Philidor", "Sicilian")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf  I assume that you means `victory_status<-chess_games$victory_status
cream_rating<-chess_games$cream_rating 
boxplot(cream_rating ~ victory_status, chess_games[!chess_games$winner %in% "draw", ])` I have a question, the font is not matching the original output, how can I fix it?

Comment: I did not know that I can filter out the way you presented, I tried different way to filter out, but they did not work.

Comment: @user432797 Actually I didn't create the variables since `boxplot` gets the location of the variables in the `data` argument. See `?boxplot` for syntax.

Comment: @user432797 Could you elaborate on "the font is not matching the original output"?

Comment: I'm referring to my question, if you look at the photos, you make carefully at (for instance) resign, the first photo shows larger size the the second photo.

Comment: @user432797 Aha, use `boxplot(..., cex.axis=1.5)`, just try a few values until you like it.

Comment: sorry for the missing words in my explanation, I meant you make carefully at (for instance) resign, the first photo shows larger font size the the second photo, I tried it and it worked, is it possible to make it bold?

Comment: @user432797 Yes, add another argument, `boxplot(..., font=2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! it is interesting they work flawlessly, but when I tried them with the legend, they did not work, so I gave up on them soon.