# Simple, why (-1)^(1/3) returns NaN when used in function?

Tags: r

I want to use a function

```
f = function(x) 
{
 f = (x-1)^(1/3)
}
```

when I put in -1 in there,  it returns NaN
but If I put the same equation on the console,
it sometimes works, but sometimes returns NaN

what should I do to get actual number from it?

Comment: Your function returns nothing btw.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write return(f) in there.

Comment: I don't see how I can sometime work and sometimes not work. When I type `(-1-1)^(1/3)` i always get NaN. That's because R doesn't use complex/imaginary numbers by defaulr (and the cubed root of -2 is complex. You could do `as.complex(-1-1)^(1/3)` to get the value.

Comment: Maybe this is related to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64191011/build-cubic-root-function-in-r-that-returns-both-negative-and-positive-numbers/

Comment: @k3b have you tried x=-1 ?

Comment: @MrFlick then, If I change the formula like this ; (-1 * x^(1/3) ) ^3, will it be okay? I think It'll skip the complex number calculation

Comment: @KarthikS This function returns something but invisibly. Try `x <- f(2)` and then type `x`, you'll get the result. But well, this is not the topic of the question.